# How to include assets in app deployed with JLink?

Tags: java, javafx, jlink

I have a JavaFX Maven project that has the following folder structure:

```
+ -- src/

+ -- -- java/
+ -- -- -- com/pkg/
+ -- -- -- -- App.java

+ -- -- resources/
+ -- -- -- com/pkg/
+ -- -- -- -- fxml/app.fxml
+ -- -- -- -- css/app.css
+ -- -- -- -- img/img.png
```

When I need to load an FXML file, for example, I do:

```java
URL url = getClass().getResource("/com/pkg/fxml/app.fxml");
```

Everything was fun and games until I tried to ship my app with JLink. I ran JLink maven goal and it created an executable in `/target/image/bin/java`. I can run it, but it soon raises `LoadException` because it couldn't find some FXML file. Indeed, I can't find any `.fxml`, `.css` or `.png` file inside `target/`, because `resources/` is not there.

So what am I doing wrong here - the file structure, or the build? And how can I fix this?

Comment: I'd put Maven in as a tag as well. The file structure looks reasonable to me. If there are any "intermediate" files where assets need to be placed, I'd check that this is happening. I've only jlinked manually/(on CLI), and sometimes forget to put assets of my source into the intermediate compiled version that I make with javac, and that is the source for jlink. Maven I would assume is set up to handle this, but I haven't used Maven for jlinking yet, so it's just a guess that is where the dots aren't connecting.

Comment: `resources` shouldn't be in target; but the contents should (i.e. you should have `target/classes/com/pkg/`, which should then contain both `App.class` and `app.fxml`, etc.) If you build a jar file, the jar should have `com` at the top level, with all those contents. I recommend building a runtime with jlink which includes the JavaFX modules you need, building a jar file with your classes and resources, and then use [`jpackage`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/jpackage/) to create the native package with the runtime and jar file.